# Как задать 1 переход для всех сцен в Ренпай?

Tags: python, renpy

В нашей новелле все сцены имеют переходы и хотелось бы 1 раз указать стандартный переход для всех сцен, а не прописывать постоянно `with`. Возможно ли такое сделать? Я прочитал обо всех переходах в `config` в документации, однако решения не нашел.

Вот пример как создаются сцены в игре (фоны), `with` - добавляет переход на выбор. `bg first day` - название фона.

```
scene bg first day with dissolve
```

Comment: Может добавить немного кода в вопрос? Хотя видимо спецов по этой штуке тут немного, но может по коду что-то поймём.

Comment: На сколько я понял нужно создать свой парсер выражений. Например в игре используется `scene <название фона>`, где `scene` типо функция, которая ставит на фон нужную картинку. Можно создать свою `_scene`, в которую уже будет встроена функция перехода, например, `dissolve`. Однако, как именно их создавать я пока не разобрался. https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/cds.html#

Comment: Если кто-то может привести пример готового парсера, либо решить мою проблему с помощью него, буду очень признателен.

Comment: http://ru.renpypedia.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Операторы,_определяемые_разработчиком_(Creator-Defined_Statements)#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.28Example.29 еще одна такая же ссылка только на русском.